# Truncating string to 125 characters in Div element

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, truncate

I have Div element having the following content

`It is a dummy text Lorem Ipsum Iswwpe ID DFDLJLKDjlk It is a dummy text Lorem Ipsum Iswwpe ID DFDLJLKDjlk It is a dummy text Lorem Ipsum Iswwpe ID DFDLJLKDjlk <a href="#">click here</a>`

I have to trim the DIV content to 125 characters and have to add 'More' link on the end.I am using DOJO library as JS library

The following code I am using for trimming and replacing with More link.But, the length is including `<a href="#"> and </a>` tags.I wan't to get only text length.

```
                var name= elm.innerHTML;                    
                if(name.length > 125){
                     var subtext = name.substring(125, feednamelength);name.replace(subtext , '<a href="#">More</a>');

                }
```

Comment: Show us your code if you have any.

Comment: can you not use a css solution does it have to be a certain amount of chars? see here for css info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @Zonder it will not clip the text upto 125 characters as it depends upon the width of element.

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib I am asking if it needs to be 125 or not they could be just trying to stop an overflow of chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is for javascript. <kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9N6s3/)</kbd>

```
function short(length) {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var len = s.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       var g = s[i].innerHTML;
       var x = ". . . More";
       var leng = length-5;
       var html = g.substring(0, leng)+"";
       var allHTML = html+x;
       s[i].innerHTML = allHTML;
    }
}
short(125);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you have to use Javascript? Not everyone has it enabled. If you have PHP on your server you could just do,

```
echo substr($inputText, 0, 125);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following css solution to a similar case. It is hover based instead of clicking "more" but behaves quite well.

```
<style type="text/css">
.longtextautoexpand {
max-width:350px;
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.longtextautoexpand:hover {
overflow:visible;
}
</style>

<p class="longtextautoexpand">
When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article      provides a solution.
</p>
```